# Undefined variable and index in delete multiple row function

Tags: php

Edit:I added this

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox']))
(get from an answer below but it seems the asnwer is gone)

and now the undefined varialbe and index error are gone...but the problem now is when I try to delete , it require check and click delete button twice to delete the selected rows...

```
  <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="insert-add.php">

<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="50"> <div align="center">#</div></th>
    <th width="91"> <div align="center">ID </div></th>
    <th width="198"> <div align="center">First Name </div></th>
    <th width="198"> <div align="center">Last Name </div></th>
    <th width="250"> <div align="center">Mobile Company </div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center">Cell </div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center">Workphone </div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center">Group </div></th>
  </tr>
    </form>
<?

    echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action=''>";

while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\" value=\"$objResult[addedrec_ID]\"></td>";
    echo "<td>$objResult[addedrec_ID] </td>";
    echo "<td>$objResult[FirstName]</td>";
    echo "<td>$objResult[LastName] </td>";
    echo "<td>$objResult[MobileCompany] </td>";
    echo "<td>$objResult[Cell] </td>";
    echo "<td>$objResult[WorkPhone] </td>";
    echo "<td>$objResult[Custgroup] </td>";

   echo "</tr>";

}


 echo "<td colspan='7' align='center'><input name=\"delete\" type=\"submit\" id=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\">";

 if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) // from button name="delete"
 {
 $checkbox = ($_POST['checkbox']); //from name="checkbox[]"
     $countCheck = count($_POST['checkbox']);

 for($d=0;$d<$countCheck;$d++)
     {
         $del_id  = $checkbox[$d];

 $sql = "DELETE from UserAddedRecord where addedrec_ID = $del_id";

 $result2=mysql_query($sql)  or trigger_error(mysql_error());;;

     }
         if($result2)
     {  
          $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript();
         }
         else
         {
 echo "Error: ".mysql_error();
         }
 }
  echo "</form>";
```

Thanks for every reply.

Comment: What's the value of `$del_if` before the query? Also, you're just asking for a SQL injection attack there.

Comment: Please post the HTML form you are attempting to process too.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your reply , I edit my question , with more complete form.

Comment: @Inerdia Thanks for your reply , I post my form already .

Comment: I would like to help you, but this is just a bunch of completely unstructured code. First think about the tasks you want to do, create a conceptual design of your code and then start writing code. This results in good code and everybody is able to read it and help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first notice is due to no $_POST["checkbox"] variable.  If you're using AJAX, inspect your query with firebug to check if you're sending a checkbox variable.

The second undefined is coming from your nesting.  See my below example:

```
$foo = 0
if($foo ==1){
    $bar = 5;
}
if($bar == 2){
    //Blah
}
```

If you were to run that then $bar would never be set, hence the notice.  As $countCheck is set to 0 as $_POST["checkbox"] is not set, then the for loop never runs hence $result2 is never set.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, you have a form nested inside another form.

```
  <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="insert-add.php">
```

and in the middle you have

```
    echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action=''>";
```

Remove the 2nd one, the "echo"'ed one that is...

Unless you close the first form, you cant launch another one inside of it...

Comment: Oops sorry I didn't copy the form completely...actually I do close the first form before the second form.

Comment: Add the right code then?I would also change $del_id  = $checkbox[$d]; to apply the intval class, which will force it to a number so you dont have to worry with SQL injections.. So it would now be $del_id  = intval($checkbox[$d]); and you can add error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); to the top of your PHP file, below the open php tag to ignore that unintialized varaible and other errors of the sort.

Comment: I removed the 2nd form tag and the for array since i do not have your database, making it basic HTML, then added a closing form tag and it worked fine. Please update with the exact code and it can be fixed?

Comment: In your new code, there is no sense in having the 2 form tags. Delete the closing form tag under the TR and delete the open form tag that you echo.

Comment: Sorry I need to go now , I will update to you tomorrow , promise . And really thanks for your replies .

Comment: I'm so sorry for my late responce Austin....I found my problem,the error is "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...." , so I just put my delete function to another php file and execute it,and it works.But I think my script is too messy , gotta rearrange it.Really sorry for being so late..